# Domain and subdomains pointing do different servers with CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

This is my first time doing this, so I have the following, I bought a domain **example.com** with Godaddy.

Now I want **example.com** to point to an AWS instance which will hold a presenation website wordpress with docker.

I want to add a subdomain **app.example.com** which should point to a different AWS instance that is using docker. Will this work with just a CNAME on godaddy?

I also need another subdomain **s1.example.com** which should point to the same AWS instance as **app.example.com** but this time the docker container has port 8080 exposed. I know in this case I will have to do a proxy pass in order for the one on 8080 to work, something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

In conclusion is my plan right? Will it work mostly just with CNAME records or is there a better way? I am a developer, not a sysadmin or devops so as I said this is my first time doing this so any feedback is appreciated, also If I haven't explained it in detail enough or you have additionl questions please let me know.

Comment: CNAMEs should work fine. The ports are a separate matter and are not really DNS related

Comment: This should work. Pointing a CNAME to your A record for your server, then having virtual hosts handle serving out separate content based on the subdomain.